# Error in tSQLStoredProc in Delphi XE2 when importing stored proc from Oracle XE 11g?

Tags: oracle, delphi, stored-procedures, oracle11g, delphi-xe4

In an Oracle database I have some stored procedures in a package. When the parameter list contain integers and I try to bind a `tSQLStoredProc` and navigate to the correct procedure, the `Param` list show the integers in the parameter list as `ftFMTBcd` instead of `ftInteger`.

As long as the integer parameters are declared as `OUT` in Oracle, transfer goes ok.

But if the integer is in the `IN` list, I get `ORA-05602` when calling the procedure.

Reason seems to be that conversion in Datasnap server of the `ftFMTBcd` field into integer just fails and Datasnap server is sending a blank string to Oracle instead of an integer or a number (both `IN INTEGER` and `IN Number` in parameter list ends up as `ftFMTBcd` which seem to end up as blank string at transfer).

Using the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE achristo_adm.paalogget(
paaloggetID       NUMBER(38, 0)    NOT NULL,
utstyrID          NUMBER(38, 0),
BrukerID          NUMBER(38, 0),
sist_paalogget    TIMESTAMP(6),
CONSTRAINT PK22 PRIMARY KEY (paaloggetID)
USING INDEX
    LOGGING)
LOGGING;
```

And following package function

```
PROCEDURE registrer_paalogget(
    FUTSTYRID       IN INTEGER,
    FBRUKERID       IN INTEGER,
    FSIST_PAALOGGET IN TIMESTAMP,
    fpaaloggetID OUT INTEGER) AS paaloggetC hl_recur_typ;
BEGIN
  OPEN paaloggetC FOR SELECT paaloggetID FROM paalogget WHERE utstyrID = FUTSTYRID;
  FETCH paaloggetC INTO fpaaloggetID;
  IF paaloggetC%notfound THEN
    fpaaloggetID := PAALOGGET_SEQ.NEXTVAL;
    INSERT
    INTO paalogget
      (
        paaloggetID,
        utstyrID,
        BrukerID,
        sist_paalogget
      )
      VALUES
      (
        fpaaloggetID,
        FUTSTYRID,
        FBRUKERID,
        FSIST_PAALOGGET
      );
    else
      update paalogget
        set 
          sist_paalogget=FSIST_PAALOGGET
      where
        utstyrID=FUTSTYRID;
  END IF;
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
   raise_application_error(-20001,'An error was encountered in registrer_paalogget - '
       ||SQLCODE||' -ERROR- '||SQLERRM);
END registrer_paalogget;
```

Will these have same problem in Delphi-XE4 ?  (Didn't find anything resembling in QC)

If still same problem in Delphi-XE4, I have to make an entry in QC :-)

Hope someone with access to both Delphi XE4 (XE3) and Oracle XE could test this.

For me the possible error is a show stopper right now.

Addon:

Could this question (which I forgot to mark as question :-( ) be involved?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17567604/is-there-something-essential-missing-or-wrong-in-this-datasnap-server-method

Comment: try to add these lines in the afterconnect event of your TSQLConnection:  SQLConnection.Params.Values['EnableBCD'] := 'true';
SQLConnection.Params.Values['IntegerPrecision']:= '10'. if it still doesn't work, change your stp parameters to NUMBER(10,0) instead of INTEGER

Comment: Hm. Can't say it helped :-(

Think I have to check if there is some substantially wrong with the Datasnap server method.

Comment: Did you test without Datasnap?

Comment: The problem is not with datasnap per se, but how tSQLstoredProc communicate with a database.

When a tSQLStoredProc is coupled to the stored procedure name (after choosing other needed variables), the PARAM fields are populated with ftFMTBCD instead of ftInteger. 

That works ok when importing results since Integer can be assigned a BCD, but assigning BCS to Integer is a failure. Which ends up sending blank string to Oracle client which in turn spit out the errror message.

Comment: Only solution seem to be to rewrite all stored procedure methods to use VARCHAR2 as parameters and converting the parameters to Integer before calling original stored procedure like in my other comment below:

Comment: PROCEDURE registrer_DNSServer
  (
    fdnsservernavn     IN VARCHAR2,
    fdnsnavnID   IN INTEGER,
    fipadresse   IN VARCHAR2,
    fipV6adresse IN VARCHAR2,
    fdnsserveriD OUT INTEGER
  )
AS
  dnsserverC hl_recur_typ;
BEGIN
  OPEN dnsserverC FOR SELECT dnsserverID FROM dnsserver WHERE dnsservernavn = fdnsservernavn;
  FETCH dnsserverC INTO fdnsserveriD;
  IF dnsserverC%NOTFOUND THEN
......
......

Comment: PROCEDURE registrer_DNSServer
  (
    fdnsservernavn     IN VARCHAR2,
    fdnsnavnID   IN varchar2,
    fipadresse   IN VARCHAR2,
    fipV6adresse IN VARCHAR2,
    fdnsserveriD OUT INTEGER
  )
AS
  fdnsnavnID1 INTEGER;
BEGIN
  registrer_DNSServer(fdnsservernavn, fdnsnavnID1, fipadresse, fipV6adresse, fdnsserveriD);
end registrer_DNSServer;

Comment: Seems like trying to register a QC seem to be futile work since noone is interested to test this, and last time I reported a bug I was strictly told to report only bugs that has been thouroughly tested by others.
Useless ressource sometimes. :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit is existing if you install ORacle XE 11g on your local computer and don't install latest instant client and copy the files that is also stored in server directory, like oci.dll etc. etc.

All the dll-files must be latest version, not the one distributed with the server.

Both transfer of integers, bcd etc. and dates do fail with original server installation.

Comment: Sounds like a legit self-answer to me?

Comment: That driver made me almost nuts :-(
So I wrote about the reason to save others times looking for the culprit.

The wrong (old) dll was activated because the path statement mentioned the Oracle server executable (with a dll with same name) before the oracle client.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved !!

If anyone was reading the included routines twice (or maybe thrice :-) there should have been triggered a huge bell, bigger than Liberty Bell :-D

NUMBER(38, 0) is in reality an 128-bit integer that is not supported in 32-bits Delphi.

Solution is to redesign the database to use BIGINT insted, which in Oracle is declared as NUMBER(19, 0) using ER-Studio Data Architect DE which is bundled with RAD Studio Architect.

There should also be implemented a new warning about 128-bits integer not supported and field converted to ftFMTBCD.

Now, why updating a record having a 128-bit integer do fail in tSQLStoredProcedure is something that maybe Embarcadero should look into. As I have understood someone else, same error message about erroneous integer export, ORA-01722: invalid number seem to happen also with tFDStoredProc.
A message about the problem has been sent the developers.

Problem arise if you model a database model in ER/Studio and declare fields as INTEGER instead of BIGINT or lower precision integers and export the model with stored procedure to Oracle database. That would end up as shpwn in original questin as NUMBER(38, 0).

Answer (score 0):

A workaround (which is of course not usable in length) is to rewrite all procedures to use only strings as parameters instead of integer and use to_number before calling original procedure

:-(

The way I do it is to rename the interfaced procedure by adding _string to the procedure name and convert integer or number parameters to string and in implementation part convert the string parameters to numbers and call original method